# Mean shift clustering and the curse of dimensionality

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, dimensionality-reduction, high-dimensional, multidimensional-scaling

I've often come across resources that mention that mean shift based clustering doesn't work well in higher dimensions. The sources are as follows:  Page 1 of https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5417725/, Page 7 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.00687.pdf. **The later states that the kernel density estimator (KDE) *breaks down* in high dimensions.**

My questions are as follows, and while a mathematically rigorous explanation would be fantastic, intuitive explanations would also be good. Thank you in advance!

**(1) First point where the curse of dimensionality starts to bother us:** Where exactly the breaking down (vanishing) of KDE prevents us from having good clusters? I see that the KDE using the kernel function $k$, has the following expression with the bandwidth $h$ in $d$ dimensions, $\hat{f_h}(x):=( \sqrt{2\pi nh})^{-d}\sum_{i=1}^{n}k(||\frac{x-x_i}{h}||^2)$, which goes to zero as $d \to  \infty$. Where exactly does it *start to* create a problem? In relevance to this, the mode estimate sequence $y_j$ obtained by successive mean shifts of the data (see equation (6) of https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X14002644), is *supposed to* converge the the modes of KDE (N.B. I didn't say they always converge, because as I understand, it's still unproved, except partially for Gaussian kernel- https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X14002644, and in one dimension - http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~aliyari/papers/PRL2.pdf). **My question is: for higher dimensions $d$, is it the convergence to the mode estimate ("mode seeking") sequence, that doesn't happen? Or, it does happen in higher dimensions as well, but slowly? If it does happen slowly, then it'd be rather a problem with computational time, and not the clustering performance, but it seems the clustering itself doesn't happen well - so mathematically, what exactly prevents it?**

(2) Is it possible to *alter* the kernel from Gaussian kernel to something else so that, the convergence of the mode estimate sequence is guaranteed?

(3) To prevent the kernel density estimate from going to zero, is it possible to *let it depend on the dimension $d$ as well*?

Comment: Just regarding "Where exactly does it start to create a problem?": This can't be said in generality because it depends on the separation between clusters. Strongly separated clusters can still be found at much higher $d$ and weaker separation causes trouble for much lower $d$.

Comment: @Lewian Thanks for your comment! Do you happen to have any reference (paper etc.) that backs up these statements? I understand that, for large dimensions, no two points are too close themselves, and hence clusters or their centers need to have higher distances to be separable enough from each other. But I'd be very interested in a quantitative estimate.

Comment: Sorry, no reference, it's experience and thinking.

Comment: Okay thank you. But do you have any intuition of why the kernel function is chosen to be a non-increasing function in the mean shift procedure?

Comment: The closer $x_i$ to $x$, the more it contributes to the density at $x$. Makes sense to me.

Comment: The thing is that for higher $d$ a kernel based on Euclidean distances can no longer *distinguish* anymore between points belonging to the same cluster and points from different clusters. One can stop the kernel from converging to zero (not much of a problem, one can have it depending on $d$), but as long as it's a function of Euclidean distances, the distinction problem cannot be solved.

Comment: @Lewian Thanks, so is the inability to distinguish between points in the same clusters vs. different clusters caused by the fact that any two different points are far apart in large dimensions $d$? What starts to go wrong about this distinctive power? Does it become true that when $d \to \infty$, the  Euclidean distance betwene any two different points also go to $\infty$?The kernel starts to go to zero, I understand, does that mean, finding the mode of the kernel density estimate (KDE, equation in the original question) becomes more difficult?

Comment: This depends on how the points are generated, but under some not too restrictive distributional assumptions distances between any two points converge to a constant: https://www.jstor.org/stable/20441411?seq=1 This also means that densities will become very flat, modes will not stick out much, and are therefore hard to find (and potentially meaningless).